# Using Firebase Realtime Database to trigger an event for all users to notifydatasetchange on Recyclerview

Tags: android, database, firebase, layout, android-recyclerview

I have a layout with 8 recyclerviews and 8 imageviews with textviews all of them set to visible with each recyclerview corresponding to a specific user.
[8 recyclerviews for 8 users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lxsgg.png)

When a user clicks on the empty mic icon, the firebase database is updated and seat is assigned in this room with the user's data, the imageview and textview visibility is set to gone and recyclerview visibility is set to visible.

The problem is when the user leaves the room, the database removes the user from that seat but the layout is disturbed for other users viewing the room. Imageview and Textview visibility are set to visible again and recyclerview visibility is set to gone. But this is not working.
[This is the layout after a user leaves the room.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CX7UC.png)

Is there any way of notifying all users to adjust the layout as soon as a user leaves the room if that user was on seat.

I have a recyclerview and imageview plus textview both at the same place for each individual mic seat.

Code for fetching data from firebase and setting visibilities

```
 private void seat1(){

    Intent i = getIntent();
    final String RoomID = i.getStringExtra(ConstantApp.ACTION_KEY_ROOM_NAME);

    RFirebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    // get reference to 'users' node
    RFirebaseDatabase = RFirebaseInstance.getReference("users" + "/" + RoomID + "/" + "seatlist" + "/");
    //Toast.makeText(this, "path " + RFirebaseDatabase, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    seat1 = new ArrayList<>();
    seatadaper1 = new SetSeatRecyclerAdapter1(this, seat1);
    seat1rec.setAdapter(seatadaper1);

    RDBListener = RFirebaseDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.child("seatone").exists()){

                aud1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                audtext1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                seat1.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot teacherSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {


                        try {
                            Users_Home upload = teacherSnapshot.getValue(Users_Home.class);
                            upload.setId(teacherSnapshot.getKey());
                            seat1.add(upload);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                }
                seatadaper1.notifyDataSetChanged();


                Toast.makeText(LiveRoomActivity.this, "seat1 " + seatadaper1.getItemCount(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else
            {
                aud1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                audtext1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }



        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            log.debug("Error =======.=============.============= => " + databaseError);

        }
    });
    seatadaper1.setOnItemClickListener(new SetSeatRecyclerAdapter1.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(int position) {

            //Toast.makeText(LiveRoomActivity.this, "clicked user => " + seat1.get(position).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onShowItemClick(int position) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onDeleteItemClick(int position) {
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Recyclerview code?

Comment: when you change visibility and fetching data from firebase.